# Foreign key interpreted as method in Sequel many_to_one association

Tags: sql, ruby, model, associations, sequel

Currently working on associations in my Sequel model.

I have a class called `Node` which manages multiple instances of a single application. The details aren't too important in the context of this question.

```
class Node < Sequel::Model(:node)

  many_to_one(:system_status, key: :node_id) { |ds| ds.where(:last_heartbeat > Time.now - HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT.seconds) }
  ...

  def get_all_system_status_of_all_live_nodes

     self.system_status

  end

end
```

The above code basically is my attempt at emulating the following join which I am refactoring/replacing (replacing joins in my model with associations):

```
MyApp::Model::Node.where { last_heartbeat > Time.now - HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT.seconds }.join(:system_status, node_id: Sequel.expr(:node__id))
```

As you can tell, the above snippet gets all "live nodes" (which is determined by a heartbeat that "beats" every few seconds) and then gets the system status in a corresponding table for each node.

Here's my problem though - when I try to run `get_all_system_status_of_all_live_nodes`, I get the following error:

```
0> self.system_status
=> undefined method `node_id' for #<MyApp::Model::Node:0x38a1c402>
```

Note: `self` returns the row values of `MyApp::Model::Node`

It seems to be interpreting `node_id` (the foreign key in `system_status`) as a method, for some reason.

EDIT:

I was able to get somewhere with:

```
  one_to_one(
    :system_status,
    :key => :node_id
  ) do |ds|
    ds.where("last_heartbeat > ?", Time.now - HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT.seconds)
  end
```

Which yielded the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM "SYSTEM_STATUS" WHERE (("SYSTEM_STATUS"."NODE_ID" = 398) AND (last_heartbeat > TIMESTAMP '2017-12-07 16:38:44.243726')) LIMIT 1
```

Looks like the JOIN still isn't being applied?

Comment: The `key` in your `many_to_one` is the column of your FK in the node table; what does your `node` table look like?  What is the column of the ID in `node` that refers back to `system_status`?

Comment: `system_status.node_id` corresponds to `node.id`.

Comment: So I just tried `:key => :id`, and I got `SELECT * FROM system_status WHERE "ID" => 123` which is a different output (and not an error).. But that's still not what I want.

Comment: Wait, something seems backwards then.  You don't have a many-to-one of nodes to system_status, it's the other way around.  You should have a `one_to-many` in `node` referring to`system_status`, and a `many_to_one` in `system_status` referring to node...

Comment: Actually, is it a `one_to_one`? This is the raw SELECT statement I am trying to emulate with my association refactor: `SELECT * FROM NODE 
 JOIN SYSTEM_STATUS ON (SYSTEM_STATUS.NODE_ID = NODE.ID) WHERE (LAST_HEARTBEAT > TIMESTAMP '2017-12-07 16:28:54.870651')`. Most importantly, I want an association where the time comparison is satisfied.

Comment: I've updated my question with an update on what I did